# How to automatically get latest version from TFS server in Team Explorer 2013?

Tags: tfs, automation, team-explorer, getlatest

We are using Team Explorer 2013 with TFS to share test scripts in our project. But, we need all the latest scripts that have been updated before we run the test suite.

We are unable to find an option in Team Explorer 2013 as suggested in other threads for Visual Studio Development environment. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How do you run the test suite?

Comment: The suite will be called from an external python script which will run periodically.

Comment: Then you can call the tf command to get the latest version in your python script before run the suite just as Cece mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can build the test scripts first, as TFS will get latest version on your build agent machine by default when you queue a build.

Option 2: Run [tf get](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) command to get latest version before you run the test suite.

> Get the latest version of all items in a workspace:
>
> ```
> c:\workspace>tf get
> ```